# Lib boost not being accessible outside main

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, c++17

I'm trying to use Boost in my project, but it is only being accessed inside `main.cpp`. If I try to include it in another file I get an error. I don't know if it's something that must be specified in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
...

include (cmake/CPM.cmake)

CPMAddPackage(
  NAME PackageProject.cmake
  GITHUB_REPOSITORY TheLartians/PackageProject.cmake
  VERSION 1.4
)

# ------------------------------   Boost    ----------------------------------
CPMAddPackage("gh:Orphis/boost-cmake#7f97a08b64bd5d2e53e932ddf80c40544cf45edf@1.71.0")
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

# Core
add_library(
  ProjectCore
  include/ProjectCore.hpp
  src/ProjectCore.cpp
  )

# Utils
add_library(
  Utils
  include/utils.hpp
  src/utils.cpp
  )

...

target_include_directories(ProjectCore PUBLIC include/)
target_include_directories(Utils PUBLIC include/)

add_executable(Project src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Project
  PUBLIC Boost::system
  PRIVATE ProjectCore
  PRIVATE Utils
  )
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set_target_properties(Project PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

I proceed with the following commands:

```sh
core$ md build && cd build && cmake ..
```

```sh
core$ bear -- make -C build
```

```sh
core$ ./build/Project
```

Trying to include boost on `main.cpp`

[image: Trying to include boost on main.cpp]

Trying to include boost on `utils.cpp`
[image: Trying to include boost on utils.cpp]

Comment: You are aware that you are not restricted to doing only what your editor thinks you can do? That you can continue and type in the name of the header file you wish to `#include`, and it's not your editor, but your compiler, that will be the final judge whether this will work, or not?

Comment: Yes, pretty aware of that, indeed I even tried to compile and the compiler said pretty much the same thing that ccls pointed me. Ccls usually is pretty accurate on what's happening on my code.

Comment: You **link** `project` executable with the Boost, so `main.cpp`, which is compiled into that executable, can see Boost includes. You **don't link** `Utils` library with the Boost, so `src/utils.cpp`, which is part of that library, cannot see Boost include. What else did you expect?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you  I end up not paying attention to this point, first time using cmake by myself, sorry for the noob mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Tsyvarev` pointed out in the main message thread, I forgot to link Boost with the other libs I wanted to use. I ended up being able to run it by adding the following line

```
target_link_libraries(Utils PRIVATE Boost::system)
```